# Is there any way to make this grid responsive without media queries?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

### Problem

So I'm coding my portfolio [website](https://voaneves.com) and I'm trying to make it fully responsible while avoiding media queries. The code provided is working. The only requirement is that I need the grid to expand with the content when the transition kicks in.

### What I've tried

This is the code which I have tried:

```css
.portfolio-content {
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card:hover {
  width: 600px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card:hover .circle::before {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(400px at center);
          clip-path: circle(400px at center);
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card:hover .circle .logo {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card:hover .content {
  left: 0;
  display: inline;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card:hover .content img {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 150%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .circle::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(min(15vw, 120px) at center);
          clip-path: circle(min(15vw, 120px) at center);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .circle .logo {
  position: relative;
  width: min(15vw, 200px);
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .content h2 {
  color: #ccc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 2.5vw, 2.5em);
  line-height: 1em;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .content p {
  color: var(--color-grey-4);
  font-size: clamp(0.8rem, 2.5vw, 1.2em);
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .content a {
  position: relative;
  color: var(--color-white);
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .content img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  height: 450px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card {
    max-width: 200px;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card:hover {
    height: 600px;
  }
  .portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card:hover .content img {
    top: initial;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%) scale(1);
    height: 300px;
  }
  .portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .card .content {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 40px;
  }
  .portfolio-content .portfolio-grid .content {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 40px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1432px) {
  .portfolio-content .portfolio-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
  .portfolio-content .portfolio-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-content">
  <div class="portfolio-grid">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/oab.webp" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>CAATO Tocantins</h2>
        <p>
          Site baseado no Wordpress. Atualizei tema, core, fiz mudanças de
          layout, estabeleci redirecionamentos e encurtei URLs, além de fazer o
          SEO.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/caato.webp" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/oab.webp" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>CAATO Tocantins</h2>
        <p>
          Site baseado no Wordpress. Atualizei tema, core, fiz mudanças de
          layout, estabeleci redirecionamentos e encurtei URLs, além de fazer o
          SEO.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/caato.webp" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/oab.webp" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>CAATO Tocantins</h2>
        <p>
          Site baseado no Wordpress. Atualizei tema, core, fiz mudanças de
          layout, estabeleci redirecionamentos e encurtei URLs, além de fazer o
          SEO.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/caato.webp" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/oab.webp" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>CAATO Tocantins</h2>
        <p>
          Site baseado no Wordpress. Atualizei tema, core, fiz mudanças de
          layout, estabeleci redirecionamentos e encurtei URLs, além de fazer o
          SEO.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/caato.webp" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/oab.webp" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>CAATO Tocantins</h2>
        <p>
          Site baseado no Wordpress. Atualizei tema, core, fiz mudanças de
          layout, estabeleci redirecionamentos e encurtei URLs, além de fazer o
          SEO.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/caato.webp" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/oab.webp" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>CAATO Tocantins</h2>
        <p>
          Site baseado no Wordpress. Atualizei tema, core, fiz mudanças de
          layout, estabeleci redirecionamentos e encurtei URLs, além de fazer o
          SEO.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/caato.webp" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/oab.webp" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>CAATO Tocantins</h2>
        <p>
          Site baseado no Wordpress. Atualizei tema, core, fiz mudanças de
          layout, estabeleci redirecionamentos e encurtei URLs, além de fazer o
          SEO.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/caato.webp" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/oab.webp" class="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h2>CAATO Tocantins</h2>
        <p>
          Site baseado no Wordpress. Atualizei tema, core, fiz mudanças de
          layout, estabeleci redirecionamentos e encurtei URLs, além de fazer o
          SEO.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Explore</a>
        <img src="https://voaneves.com/assets/img/port/caato.webp" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, what the code is doing is creating a grid that reduces the number of columns 2 times (with 1432px and 970px).

Changing it does not work as intended, because it becomes unflexible (doesn't expand).

### My Research

I tried to set the grid columns with auto-fit, and while it does work, it doesn't expand:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
```

Tried to set grid colums to auto, it didn't fit also.

```
grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
```

Tried to set flexbox and this is the closest one, but the animation becomes buggy:

```
.portfolio-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I've googled it, searched websites and the answers are various, but didn't fit the scope of my problem.

### Question

So my basic question is, how do I keep this grid responsive, while avoiding media queries and making the cards expansible?

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with media queries?

Comment: It only makes the code longer, harder to make changes and looks hacky for me (probably we don't even need it anymore: https://dev.to/kathryngrayson/you-probably-dont-need-media-queries-anymore-a4j)

Comment: [check this](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-make-responsive-layouts-without-using-css-media-queries) another method like flex-wrap

Comment: flex-wrap did the same as grid without the media queries. The only thing is that the transitions became buggy. Can you please provide a snipped for me to have a look?

Comment: I would use an old and crusty media query.

Comment: @morganney, the code provided is working. My question is how to avoid it

Comment: @Neves4 I know and I am saying I would not avoid it.

Comment: @Neves4 your code working fine, the only issue is that some elements go off the `viewport`. so to avoid that, my advice is to use `%` for all `width` in all elements. with good management for that, you can achieve what you want without query. also, you will have to manage font size too.

Comment: @Mad7Dragon, would you mind to elaborate a little bit more about the percentages? If I define percentages, wouldn't I have a problem with columns size? more specifically, how would I handle wrapping?

Comment: you can set `min-width` with pixel, but make sure it's always enough for small screens. Is the element going off the viewport the only problem, or are there any other problems?

Comment: @Mad7Dragon I didn't find other problems, but am having trouble whilst implementing it with pixels, because when I resize the screen the grid continues with 3 columns, just thinner columns